# Deleting App should not delete Document Directory

Tags: ios, iphone, nsfilemanager

Is there any way not to Delete document Directory If iOS App is get unnistaled or any alternate way

or

Is there any way we can save data on different place so that after deleting app we can use it?

Comment: All I know about this is you could not do any thing when the application is get uninstaled.

Comment: enable cloud storage for it, it can be backed up and restore when reinstall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is **no way to prevent system from deleting the documents folder** once you **uninstall the app**.

And if an **iCloud** is enabled in the device, it will backup the contents of the Documents directory. iCloud way is the most efficient as it handles documents folder content automatically, it puts data back from the backup after reinstalling, so you can reuse it.

> Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the /Documents directory and will be automatically backed up by iCloud.

More: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html

A user may also have backed up these data with **iTunes**.

Read more about file system and logic:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: Is there any way we can save data on different place so that after deleting app we can use it?

Comment: So only we can save data outside sandbox on public access folder like music